# Apply a design pattern to solve this problem and not use if/else

Tags: php, design-patterns

I am trying to improve my skills with design patterns, so please be easy on me :) In my university I often have to deal with problems where the algorithm is defined, but data structures it is working on are different.

I have the following problem:

- If the client is under 18, reduce the base price by 10%.
- If the city is ‘London’ the price of the product is 1$.
- If the client has a membership type of ‘gold’ the product is free
  (£0).

so I tried this:

```
    if($customer <18) {
    $price = $price-10;
} 

if($city == "London") {
    $price = 1;
}

if($client->membership == "gold") {
    $price = 0;
}
```

How can I make it in a nice pattern, like Factory or Strategy? Are they the right one? If not could you tell me which one and give me an example?

Comment: Factory No, strategy Maybe.  I think just put that logic in a method and return the price.

Comment: dependency injection ??

Comment: I had a look strategy but it's not easy to make it because the examples I have are no the same as mine.

Comment: The code on it's own is fine, it would depend on the code using it if you would need a pattern.

Comment: Yes I really need a pattern and not to use if/else.

Comment: Are these rules cumulative or exclusive?  Do you ever take 10% off of the dollar?  Obviously the "Gold Member" rule (pronounced with Austin Powers voice) should be run first and implement an early `return` as it renders other rules useless.

Comment: Somewhere you'll have to use `if` or `select` regardless.

Comment: And if they are under 18 in London is the price 10% off of 1 or `.90` ?

Comment: the conditions are separated, 0.9

Comment: why you need pattern for this? These are properties of object. Make your object smart like in DDD principle instead of make dumb data container.

Comment: This is the reason: Implementing these examples should be sufficient to demonstrate the flexibility of the pattern you’ve used, feel free to add your own scenarios if you would like.

Comment: if you need configure and create object with that setup, the factory is right IMHO

Comment: Might you [edit] your question to show your own musings of writing a Factory pattern or Strategy pattern as a replacement for your conditions?